# In Facebook Integration when i click on the login button it shows loading and returns to the main screen?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am doing facebook integration in my project. but the problem is when i click on the facebook login button it is showing loading and retrun to the main screen.Can anyone tell me what is the problem ?

This is my MainActivity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FacebookData mFacebookData;
    private Button mLoginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFacebookData = new FacebookData();
        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                callFacebookLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void callFacebookLogin() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            Log.e("session :", "session already build");


            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                    if (user != null) {

                        String str = user.getName();

                        try {


                            String id = user.getId();
                            String firstname = user.getFirstName();
                            String lastname = user.getLastName();
                            String pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
                            Log.e("id....", id);
                            Log.e("firstname....", firstname);

                            mFacebookData.setId(id);
                            mFacebookData.setFirstname(firstname);
                            mFacebookData.setLastname(lastname);
                            mFacebookData.setPicture(pic);


                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }


                }
            });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        } else {

            Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {


                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        if (state == SessionState.OPENED) {

                            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {


                                    if (user != null) {

                                        String str = user.getName();


                                    }

                                    try {

                                        String id = user.getId();
                                        String firstname = user.getFirstName();
                                        String lastname = user.getLastName();
                                        String pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/"
                                                + id
                                                + "/picture?type=large";


                                        mFacebookData.setId(id);
                                        mFacebookData.setFirstname(firstname);
                                        mFacebookData.setLastname(lastname);
                                        mFacebookData.setPicture(pic);


                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            });

                            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
                        }

                    }


                }
            });


        }

    }
}
```

This is my Manifest :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aaa.examplepractise">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/APP_ID" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Logcat :-

```
09-27 10:35:24.405 20441-20615/com.example.aaa.examplepractise E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
09-27 10:35:24.582 20441-20441/com.example.aaa.examplepractise E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
09-27 10:35:24.583 20441-20441/com.example.aaa.examplepractise E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
```

Comment: justpost what you are getting logcat.. set Log in onActivityResult function

Comment: Also facebook has changed the sdk version to 4.0 + in which they work on fragments not in activity I think you are using old version

Comment: @PreetikaKaur I updated my code. please see the logcat. I think it does  not giving any error.And i am using Activity not the fragment.should i use fragment instead of the activity.

Comment: which sdk version you are using ?

Comment: I am using the third party library for that . it is                                    compile 'com.github.asne.facebook:facebook:3.17.2'

Comment: On which device (android version) you are running your application ?